# I am trying to install my ejabberd from dockerfile , image is building succesfully but when i hit the run command container exits immediately

Tags: git, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile, ejabberd

After running the container it exits immediately.
How am i suppose to keep this container and ejabberd running?
What changes should i make in dockerfile?
Any help is appreciated.

Here is my dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN set -x && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        make \
        automake \
        gcc \
        g++\
        libexpat1 \
        libexpat1-dev \
        libyaml-0-2 \
        libyaml-dev \
        erlang \
        openssl \
        zlib1g \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libpam0g \
        libtext-iconv-perl \
        libssl-dev\
        git \
        postgresql postgresql-contrib     

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10 && \
    echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" |  tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list \
    apt-get install mongodb-org

RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh

ADD /.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa


RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN git clone git@bitbucket.org:sample.git

RUN cp -a /sample/. /opt/ejabberd/

RUN  cd /opt/ejabberd && ./autogen.sh && ./configure --enable-user=root --enable-mysql && make && make install

EXPOSE 5280

RUN cd /opt/ejabberd/

RUN chmod +x /opt/ejabberd/run.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/ejabberd/run.sh"]
```

Here is **run.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

cd /opt/ejabberd

exec sbin/ejabberdctl start "$@"
```

My **build** command is :

```
sudo docker build --no-cache=true -t sample:ejabb .
```

My **run** command is :

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5280:5280 -p 5269:5269 -p 5222:5222 -p 4560:4560 sample:ejabb
```

---

**Thank you.**

Comment: In run command, don't use `-d` flag. So that you may know what errors are shown before container exits. Then update the question with errors you are getting before the container exits. FYI, `-d` means detached

Comment: If running `sbin/ejabberdctl start "$@"` causes ejabberdctl to go into the background, this would cause your container to exit immediately.  The foreground process in the container must not exit.

Comment: why don't you try this image? https://hub.docker.com/r/rroemhild/ejabberd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks?tab=profile ejabberd process was going into background and hence the container was closing.

so "sbin/ejabberdctl foreground" did the trick.

Thanks.